# Class variables of same type as the class

Tags: python, oop

Messing around with the typical Point class example when learning Python, I noticed that for some reason I can't have a class level (static variable) of the same type as that of the class. E.g.

```
class Point:

  ORIGIN = Point() # doesn't work

  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

while the same works in Java:

```java
class Point {
    private static final Point ORIGIN = new Point(0, 0);
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

The question is: is there any way of achieving the same in Python. Right now I am relying on module level variables and I'm not liking that solution. Also, is there any reason why it can't be done in the body of the class?

Comment: "Right now I am relying on module level variables and I'm not liking that solution"  Why not?  Module-level globals make a lot more sense then weird static final variables hidden inside class definitions.  What's wrong with a simpler solution?

Comment: @S.Lott: The reasoning being that the ORIGIN does *not* belong to any module. If for e.g. I decide to move this class to some other module, the way ORIGIN is referenced always remains the same.

Comment: put ORIGIN is an instance of Point, and belongs to the same module Point does.  If you move one, why wouldn't you move the other?

Comment: It's kind of a moot point, as `ORIGIN` would make more sense as an attribute of a `CoordinateSystem` class than of `Point`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create an instance of a class, until that class is actually created, which is after the class body is evaluated (note: it's executed like normal Python code).

The same goes for your Java example: ClassLoader creates the `Point` class and then executes the code from `static` fields.

A rough equivalent of a class loader in Python is the metaclass, so you could do something like this:

```
def class_with_static(name, bases, body):
    static_block = body.pop("__static__", None)
    klass = type(name, bases, body)
    if static_block:
        static_block(klass)
    return klass

class Point(object):
    __metaclass__ = class_with_static

    def __static__(cls):
        cls.ORIGIN = cls()

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

assert isinstance(Point.ORIGIN, Point)
assert Point.ORIGIN.x == Point.ORIGIN.y == 0
assert not hasattr(Point, "__static__")
```

Of course this will have some other consequences, like: all subclasses of `Point` will have an `ORIGIN` attribute of their own. So you probably just want to do it like others shown :)

Comment: Good explanation; but the problem here seems to be that in Java the `ORIGIN` class level variable is initialized only *after* the entire class is loaded but in case of Python it tries to look for Point and fails, which actually shouldn't have been the case. I have tried to think up a good reason as to why this isn't allowed in Python but can't come up with any. As others have pointed out, the most clean solution here would be to attach ORIGIN property to the class *after* its declaration. :-(

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact, that you're treating `class` as a declaration, while it's in fact an expression, which stores it's result in a module-level name "Point". You can't have recursive expressions in Python, so you can't reference 'Point' in expression that will be used as a value of 'Point'.

Comment: I guess when you say expression, you mean in a python specific way, right? Because normally expressions can be assigned to variables which doesn't seem to be the case here. So does it mean that the Python runtime traverses the code sequentially, treats module level class, function and variable declarations as expressions and assigns them to the module property? Any article where I can find the details of how these things (classes, the program execution) work under the hood in depth? Thanks.

Comment: **TO FUTURE READERS**: Most people coming to this question will want the much simpler answer after this (put the assignment to class variable in its own statement, AFTER the class declaration).

Comment: You shouldn't be inventing your own `__static__` dunder-style variables because they might conflct with future interpreter-defined "magic" names — according to the end of the [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) section of PEP 8 which says: "Never invent such names; only use them as documented."

Answer (score 16):

```
class Point(object):
  pass

Point.ORIGIN = Point()
```

Answer (score 9):

Assign it after the fact:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y


Point.ORIGIN = Point()
```

Comment: That's a module level variable which is exactly what I don't want to end up with. :-)

Comment: No, it isn't. The **assignment** is at module level, but the **value** is stored as an attribute of the Point class.

Comment: Indeed; wrong on my part. The point being, this is pushing the class level declaration outside of the class. Python can have normal class and instance level declarations *within* the class declaration so why not this one? Is this a shortcoming of the language? If not, what is the rationale behind not allowing types to refer themselves?

Comment: The name `Point` doesn't exist until the end of the class body.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a class decorator, although I'm not sure what a good name for it would be. Here's how:

```
def add_class_var(name, *args, **kwrds):
    def decorator(cls):
        setattr(cls, name, cls(*args, **kwrds))
        return cls
    return decorator

@add_class_var('ORIGIN')
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

print Point.ORIGIN, Point.ORIGIN.x, Point.ORIGIN.y
# <__main__.Point instance at 0x00B5B418> 0 0
```

Although not utilized in the above code, you can also pass arguments to the class's `__init__()`  constructor indirectly through the decorator.