# Can a python class have a class variable of this same class?

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I want my class to have a class variable whose value is of that same class:

```
class XY:
    Origin = XY(0,0)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

however, this fails with

```
    Origin = XY(0,0)
NameError: name 'XY' is not defined
```

Apparently, I can do

```
class XY:
    ...
XY.Origin = XY(0,0)
```

instead - is this really the right way?

Comment: why do you want it to be a class attribute?  just for namespacing?  probably more idiomatic to just define `C_ONE = C(1)` as a module level constant

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is - yes, it's the right way. I would add a type hint for readability:

```
class ClassName:
    Origin: 'ClassName'
```

There is actually a similar question [Class variables of same type as the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369814/class-variables-of-same-type-as-the-class). Some solutions are over-complicated, and I can't imagine use cases for them really.

Answer (score 0):

Would a "metaclass" work any better for you? Perhaps something like:

```py
class XY_Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.Origin = cls(0, 0)

class XY(metaclass=XY_Meta):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

point = XY(10, 10)
print(point.x, point.y, point.Origin.x, point.Origin.y)
```

I think that might give you:

```
10 10 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [anentropic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76622435/can-a-python-class-have-a-class-variable-of-this-same-class/76622627#comment135093307_76622435). Presumably your `XY` class lives within a  file. This provides a namespace. `Origin` can then live within that namespace and be imported as a qualified or unqualified name as the user of that module sees fit.

```
% cat coords.py 
class XY:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

origin = XY(0, 0)

% python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Mar 10 2023, 20:16:38) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import coords
>>> coords.origin
<coords.XY object at 0x11000a970>
>>> from coords import origin as xy_origin
>>> xy_origin
<coords.XY object at 0x11000a970>
```